# General system exception happened Additional data

Tags: magento2, product, error, import, export

Getting This Error while importing the products

**General system exception happened
Additional data: Error in data structure: entity values are mixed**

Screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/k5dv5AQBJMCN.png

Here's the first-row content: https://ctxt.io/2/AABQL4rSEA

Please help to resolve this error.

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: @SohelRana 2.4.6 p3